Azure DevOps: Build docker image and run tasks in container using local image
I am trying to use Windows containers as agents in ADO pipelines. The image is a custom one and dockerfile is in the same repo with the code which will run in the container. The container host is self-hosted. My idea was to build the image before running the steps in the container. This is not possible though as no steps can be added before the container initialization. Building can be done in a separate job and this will work as long as there is just one container host. If there are more the only way to accomplish this is by constantly pushing and pulling from private container registry.
I am new to containers and at this point I don't see any advantage of using registry in this scenario. Also pushing and pulling is rather slow. This seems to be barely a workaround for a missing feature in ADO.
Is there any way to make this work without using private registry?
